# Number of total records

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm quite new using AWK. I just discover the `FNR` variable. I just wonder if it is possible to get the number of total records **before** processing the file?
So the `FNR` at the end of the file.

I just need it to do something like that

```
awk 'FNR<TOTALRECORDS-4 {print}'
```

In order to delete the 4 last lines of the files.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merely want to print all but the last 4 lines of a file, use a different tool.  But if you are doing some other processing with awk and need to incorporate this, just store the lines in a buffer and print them as needed.  That is, store the most recent 4 lines, and print the last one in the buffer when you get a newline.  For example:

```
awk 'NR>4 { print a[i%4]} {a[i++%4]=$0}' input
```

This keeps 4 lines in the array `a`.  If we are in the first 4 lines of the file, do nothing but store the line in `a`.  If we are on a line greater than 4, the first thing you do is print the line 4 lines back (stored in `a` at index `i%4`)  You can put commands that manipulate `$0` between these two action statements as needed.

Comment: for i in \`seq 1 16\`; do echo $i ; done  |  awk '{a[i++%4]=$0} END { for (i=0; i<length(a);i++){ print a[i]} }'

Comment: The trouble with printing a[0]-a[3] in END is that it changes the order if the total number of lines is not a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last 4 lines from a file, you can just use `head`:

```
head -n -4 somefile > outputfile
```